# How to change local IP for external in chat using sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, chat, datagram

I created a chat in java.
it uses internal IP network but I want to change it to work with external ip also. What should I modify in my code?

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   

    String ip = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o IP", "192.168.0.");
    int porta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a Porta", "5000"));

   Conexao conexao =  new Conexao(ip, porta);

    JanelaChat j = new JanelaChat(conexao);
    j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    j.setVisible(true);
}
```

Window chat

```
public class JanelaChat extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Observer {

private Conexao conexao;
public JanelaChat(Conexao conexao) {        
   // super("chat");
    this.conexao = conexao; 
    initComponents();
    conexao.addObserver(this);
    escreve("Chat iniciado com " + conexao.getIp() + ":" + conexao.getPorta());
    mensagemjTextArea.requestFocusInWindow();
}

private void envia() {
    if (!mensagemjTextArea.getText().isEmpty()) {
        conexao.envia(mensagemjTextArea.getText());
        escreve("Você disse: " + mensagemjTextArea.getText());
        mensagemjTextArea.setText("");
    }
}

private void escreve(String texto) {
    chatjTextArea.append(texto + "\n");
    if (!chatjTextArea.getText().isEmpty() && !chatjTextArea.isFocusOwner()) {
        chatjTextArea.setCaretPosition(chatjTextArea.getText().length() - 1);
    }

}
 private void enviarjButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    envia();
}

private void mensagemjTextAreaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        envia();
    }
}
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    escreve(conexao.getMensagem());
}
```

and the connection of code is where I have the socket.

```
public class Conexao extends Observable {

private String ip;
private int porta;
private String mensagem;

public Conexao(String ip, int porta) {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.porta = porta;
    new Thread(new Recebe()).start();
}

public String getMensagem() {
    return mensagem;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public int getPorta() {
    return porta;
}

public void envia(String texto) {
    new Thread(new Envia(texto)).start();
}

public void notifica(String mensagem) {
    this.mensagem = mensagem;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

class Recebe implements Runnable {

    byte[] dadosReceber = new byte[65508];
    boolean erro = false;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(getPorta());
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            erro = false;
            while (!erro) {
                DatagramPacket pacoteRecebido = new DatagramPacket(dadosReceber, dadosReceber.length);
                try {
                    socket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
                    socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                    String s = new String(pacoteRecebido.getData(), pacoteRecebido.getOffset(), pacoteRecebido.getLength());
                    String nome = pacoteRecebido.getAddress().toString() + " disse:";
                    notifica(nome + s);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("erro");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    erro = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Envia implements Runnable {

    String texto;

    public Envia(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] dados = texto.getBytes();

        try {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(getIp());
            DatagramPacket pacote = new DatagramPacket(dados, dados.length, addr, getPorta());
            clientSocket.send(pacote);
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm learning this socket area still hopefully I have been clear in my codes.

Comment: Just change what's entered into the dialog box. There is no code here that depends on the IP being local. Whether your datagrams will get through your ISP is another question, but not a programming question.